# How to return a dictionary in parallel processing in spark?

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, lambda, rdd

I have an array of objects to process:  `Objects`, and I have a function which takes in a dictionary, and an object, and returns the same dictionary, modified:

```
new_dict = modify_object_dict(object_dict, object)
```

`modify_object_dict` does the following:

- adds a key to the dictionary which is the name of the object processed
- creates a dictionary as a value to that key (dictionary within a dictionary), which has elements added to and deleted from it.
- For example, the object might be a file:  `object_dict['file_name']=sub_dictionary`, and the sub-dictionary might contain `sub_dictionary['file_attribute']=attribute`.

`modify_object_dict` populates these sub-dictionaries, as shown above, and the result is one dictionary that holds the sub-dictionaries.

NOTE that the sub-dictionaries do not interact with each other.  i.e. the dictionary for one object does not interact with the dictionary of another object.

I wish to parallelize the processing of these objects using spark:

```
object_dict = {}   # dictionary is initially empty
RDD = (sc.parallelize(Objects)
   .map(lambda object: modify_object_dict(object_dict, object))
```

Is this the proper way to do this?  If not, what is the correct way to return a dictionary that is modified every time the mapping function is called?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't modify a variable that exists on the driver as the tasks are operated on within the executors. What does `modify_object_dict()` do? Perhaps, you can apply your processing in the tasks and then leverage `collectAsMap()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the correct way to return a dictionary that is modified every time the mapping function is called?

Short answer is there is none. Since every partition is processed separately there is no way to create a shared object with read / write access. Spark supports only two types of shared variables, accumulators and broadcasts, with write-only and read-only access respectively.

Long answer depends on what exactly is going on inside `modify_object_dict`. If operation you use is associative and commutative and can be performed on a key basis (each object can be mapped to operation on specific key) you can use some variant of `aggregateByKey`. It is also possible to partition data and process locally using `mapPartitions`.

If `modify_object_dict` doesn't meet above criteria then Spark is most likely not a good choice here. It is possible to push state to external system but it usually doesn't make sense unless Spark is used for heavy lifting and all you push outside is final results.

Moreover you shouldn't use `map` for side effects. Correct method in this case is usually `foreach`. There is also a more subtle problem here. There is no guarantee that `map` (or `foreach` for that matter) will be executed only once for each element. It means that every operation you perform has to be idempotent.

**Edit**:

Based on your description it seems you can try a following approach:

- first lets create `RDD` a dummy class:

  ```
  class Foobar(object):
      def __init__(self, name, x=None, y=None, z=None):
          self.name = name
          self.x = x
          self.y = y
          self.z = z
  ```

  and a RDD of objects:

  ```
  objects = sc.parallelize([
      {"name": "foo", "x": 1}, {"name": "foo", "y": 3},
      {"name": "bar", "z": 4}
  ]).map(lambda x: Foobar(**x))
  ```
- next lets convert it to `PairwiseRDD` with name as key and object as a value. If object is large you can extract only the fields of interest and use these as a value. I assume each object has `name` property.

  ```
  pairs = objects.map(lambda obj: (obj.name, obj))
  ```
- either `groupByKey` and transform values:

  ```
  rdd = pairs.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda iter: ...)
  ```

  or `aggregateByKey` (recommended):

  ```
  def seq_op(obj_dict, obj):
      # equivalent to modify_object_dict
      # Lets assume it is as simple as this
      obj_dict.update((k, getattr(obj, k)) for k in ("x", "y", "z"))
      return obj_dict

  def comb_op(obj_dict_1, obj_dict_2):
      # lets it is a simple union
      obj_dict_1.update(obj_dict_2)
      return obj_dict_1

  dicts = pairs.aggregateByKey({}, seq_op, comb_op)
  ```
- at this moment you have a RDD of pairs `(name, dict)`. It could be used for further processing or if you really need a local structure collected as map:

  ```
  dicts.collectAsMap()
  ## {'bar': {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': 4},
  ##     'foo': {'x': None, 'y': 3, 'z': None}}
  ```

Comment: Is the last paragraph due to partition replication?

Comment: @RohanAletty No, it is simply a matter of resilience. If executor is lost and cluster manger can recover from that task be can rescheduled on another machine. If data is not cached then obviously it will be executed on each access to the descendant rdds, and so on.  The only guarantee you have is that output from an action or a transformation is correct.

Comment: What does it mean \*\*x in this case? (I know x**y means raise x to the y power)

Comment: @J.Bend it's called the dictionary unpacking operator. It unpacks dictionaries, for example, to allow easy merging.